# How to Send, Store, Handle base64 jpeg image on server side?

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb

I am hosting a local server on my PC for a personal web app. I don't know how best practice to handle it.

How should i send it and where should i store it( in mongodb or as a file).
Currently the problems i am facing is  -

If i click a pic in total darkness i am able to send the base64 data to nodejs and store it in mongodb.  But if image is clear then i get server code - 0 and http error.  my guess is that it's something to do with data size? I checked, Server isn't reciiving any request when image is clear.

Error I am getting -

[image]

My second question is -
I am trying to save base64 in mongodb as a string. Is it a good idea? or should i store it some other way.
(1000-10000 Maximum images i am gonna store in a year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it in MongoDB but it worked for other Databases.

Try saving it as byteArray. Here's the code to help you with:

```
onFileUpload(event) {
    const files = event.target.files, f = files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    reader.onload = function () {
    let fileByteArray: any;
    if ((reader.result as string).split("base64,").length === 2) {
      fileByteArray = (reader.result as string).split("base64,")[1];
      }
    // call API to store data 
    }
  }
```